# Зачем оборачивать параметры функции в фигурные скобки?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Для чего параметры пишут в таком виде и как это работает?

```
checkout ({ commit, state }, products) {
    const savedCartItems = [...state.items]
}
///
pushProductToCart (state, { id }) {}
```

Comment: [деструктуризация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данная запись позволяет занести нужные свойства параметра сразу в отдельные переменные.

Доступно это с помощью [деструктуризации объекта](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

И данная запись равносильна:

```
checkout (actions, products) {
    const commit = actions.commit;
    const state = actions.state;

    const savedCartItems = [...state.items]
}
```